# Phased updates stuck on 0%?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

Greetings Ubuntu Community,

I use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update my 22.04 LTS install. I typically run the command a couple times throughout the week. I've noticed though for over a week now that some phased updates are still being kept back, but this has been unchanged for over a week now. They were phased at 80% last I checked last week, but have now been stuck on 0%. Anyone able to shed any light or insight into this would be most appreciated.

When running the update command, here are the packages currently being phased and held back:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libspeechd2 libsystemd0 libudev1 python3-speechd
  speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
  systemd systemd-oomd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
```

Normally, I can check the phased progress with `apt-cache policy` so in this case I'll pick the `systemd-oomd` package, but any of the above packages can be substituted too of course.

```
scott@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy systemd-oomd
systemd-oomd:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.6
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.6 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

As you can see it's phased at 0% and has been that way since last week. Earlier last week it was around 80% when I last checked, so I'm wondering what, if anything, might be going on? Just very curious as this is my first time using Ubuntu again in many years. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

0% could mean two things: Either phasing just began OR phasing was paused.

Since it's been over a week, you know it's the latter (phasing was paused).

Let's look at `systemd-oomd` at https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/phased-updates.html :

[image]

Sure enough, it shows that there was a reported error that caused phasing to be paused. We don't get to see the error report (it's private), so we don't know details about the problem or when a solution will be released.

If we wanted to dig some more, we could note the "signer, creator" fields. Those developers happen to work the Ubuntu Foundations team, so looking at their [most recent weekly update](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/foundations-team-updates-thursday-22-september-2022/30783/3) shows that enr0n was indeed working on systemd:

> systemd
> Opened PR for systemd 251.4-1ubuntu6 ([https://code.launchpad.net/~enr0n/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+git/systemd/+merge/430153](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eenr0n/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+git/systemd/+merge/430153)), thanks @jawn-smith for sponsoring
>
> - Fixed LP 1990278 “systemd-resolved not included in Ubuntu bootstrap”
> - Fixed LP 1989969 “autopkgtest TEST-36-NUMAPOLICY failure on ppc64el”
> - Fixed LP 1990187 “systemd-resolved recommends libnss-resolve in kinetic […]”
>   Followed up on comments on LP 1981622 “mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)”

Now you know everything public about what's going on, and how to find out for yourself.

In general, pauses in phasing typically last a week or two. (That's informational -- not a promise). Pauses are NOT forgotten or ignored by the developers; a broken upgrade that requires pausing tends to be a high-priority event.

**Update**: 24 hours later, phasing jumped from 0% to 90%. This suggests that the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much that sums it all up perfectly! I do follow the Ubuntu Discourse as well, so I'll keep a better eye on the Team Update posts. And thanks also for the anecdotal information as well, it helps to know I should be waiting at least a week or two with this issue before getting concerned or diving deeper into the matter. Great answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the very informative links.

Comment: What if apt policy shows `phased 0%` for a package but Canonical's info page shows it at 80%?  That's what's happening to me right now with ubuntu-advantage-tools for 22.04 LTS.